# How do I randomise the order of a foreach(glob?

Tags: php, sorting, shuffle

I'm getting a list of all PDFs that are located within a specific directory, but I want to make it a random list which changes order each time the page loads. Would I use shuffle() here and if so, how?

```
foreach(glob('../'.$town_array['city'].'/*.pdf') as $filename){
```

Thank you

Comment: Store the glob return in a var, and shuffle it. Then loop through that var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `shuffle()` here:

```
$pdfs = glob('../'.$town_array['city'].'/*.pdf');

shuffle($pdfs);

foreach($pdfs as $filename){ … }
```